# Performing a Mediation Analysis for Fixed Effects Model using bootstrap

Tags: panel-data, bootstrap, stata, fixed-effects-model, mediation

I'd like to perform a mediation analysis using a fixed effects regression model. My understanding is, that I 1) calculate the base model without the moderator 2) calculate a FE regression of the IVs on the moderator and 3) the full model of the IVs and the moderator on the DV and than check wether the indirect effect is significant using bootstrapping. I have calculated the following so far:

```
egen companyid = group(Company), label lname(companyid)
xtset companyid PeriodQ


* Total Effect (Dependent Variable on Independent Variable:)
xtreg DV $IVs $controls i.year, fe vce(robust)

*IV regressed on Mediator (path a)
xtreg M $IVs $controls i.year, fe vce(robust)

* Dependen Variable regressed on mediator and independen variable
xtreg DV $IVs $controls M i.year, fe vce(robust)

* Check significance via Bootstrap 

xtset, clear

bootstrap ([M]_b[IV]*[DV]_b[M]), bca reps(1000) nodots cluster(companyid) : xtreg (M $IVs $controls)(DV M $IVs $controls) `if' `in'
estat boot, percentile bc bca
```

But the bootstrapping does not work and I think I haven't completely understood how the command works.
So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the overall approach correct?
2. How do I have to adapt the bootstrapping command? As mentioned I try to answer the question whether the indirect/directeffect is significant and what extend of the total effect is explained via the indirect/direct effect

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. I'm using Stata 13 on Windows and I asked the same question [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1560531-performing-a-mediation-analysis-for-fixed-effects-model-using-bootstrap)

Comment: You might clarify what "does not work" means precisely (or provide an example on a public dataset that anyone can run).

Comment: Mostly answered on Statalist at the link at the bottom of the question.